# Разделить текст с числом на два столбца (текст и число отдельно)

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Как в exel можно разделить текст с числами в одном столбце на 2 столбца: отдельно текст и отдельно числа?

Пример текста

[image: неотсортированный текст]

Пример разделенного текста

[image: разделенный текст]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формула Excel

```
=ПРАВСИМВ(A1;ДЛСТР(A1) - (ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ЕСЛИ(ЕОШИБКА(НАЙТИ(" ";A1));A1;ПРАВСИМВ(A1;ДЛСТР(A1)-НАЙТИ("~";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"~";ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"")))))))))
```

[image: результат]

Answer (score 1):

- Число в тексте справа.

Извлекаем текст до первого числового символа:

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;МИН(ПОИСК({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A2&1234567890))-2)
```

Правую часть (числовое значение) можно извлечь подобным образом:

```
=--ПСТР(A2;МИН(ПОИСК({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A2&1234567890));99)
```

или так:

```
=--ПРАВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";99));99)
```

Но это если извлекается только число, без получения левой части текста. При наличии первой формулы достаточно удалить лишнее:

```
=--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;B2;)
```

- Если числовое значение находится между текстовыми фрагментами (на рисунке - строки 7, 8):

получаем число:

```
=--ЛЕВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПСТР(A7;МИН(ПОИСК({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0};A7&1234567890));99);" ";ПОВТОР(" ";9));9)
```

удаляем число из текста:

```
  =ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A7;C7&" ";)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Если число слева.

Тут совсем просто:

```
=--ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Извлечение цены в столбец как отдельного слова с конца строки:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПРАВСИМВ(A1;ДЛСТР(A1)-НАЙТИ("*";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"*";ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;" ";"")))));A1)
```

Получение наименования с помощью замены и удаления лишних пробелов:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;D1; ))
```

[image: Иллюстрация]

Подробнее познакомиться с работой со строками вы можете, например [здесь](https://golos.io/excel/@tdots/izvlechenie-slov-iz-teksta-v-excel).